# How to a generate a report that shows all of the calls, within a specific date range, Leads tab? Is that possible without using Call Center?

Tags: leads, activities, custom

I am only able to view reports on Events and Tasks associated with Activities. I cannot view calls. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

"calls" is generally the subject for Activities that are a call.  You could subset your report by the subject and see if that gets you what you want.

Comment: Also potentially Task Type is 'Call'